# How to have multiple MVC partial pages loaded via javascript, yet have different IDs for HTML elements?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a list of elements that are displayed on an MVC web page.  in each row of the list, I have a link that, when clicked, opens a javascript popup (using qtip2 tooltip plugin) with a single text field and a "save" button. The popup contains a partial MVC page that accepts a viewmodel that has the ID of the database record to update, and the existing text, if any

My problem is, the partial page has the code to handle clicking the save button.  But the way I am doing the javascript, if I want to reference an HTML element, I need them to have unique identifiers since they will be loaded multiple per page.

Example of my partial page

```
<script>
   $(function (e) {
    $(I NEED AN ID HERE THAT REFERENCES THIS FROM ID).on('click', '.mySubmit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        SubmitChange(e.target);
    });

});

function SubmitChange(e) { //

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: globalBaseUrl + "Appointment/EditROAjax/",
        data: HOW DO I REFERENCE THE FORM ID HERE?,
        context: $(this),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
                $(e).closest('form').html(data.content);
            }
            else {
                $(e).closest('form').html(data.content);
            }
        },
        error: function (a) {
            ErrorMessageDialog('Error', 'OK');
        }
    });
}
</script>

<form id="I NEED AN ID HERE" method="post" action="/MyController/MyAction"
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TextToSave)%>
<%: Html.ActionLink("SAVE", "MyAction", "MyController", null, new { id = "mySubmit", @class="mySubmit;" })%>
```

When I activate more than one of these (using qtip to load the partial page as a popup), hitting "SAVE" always takes the form Id of whatever was the most recently opened. For example: I open the popup for form ID =1, but don't save yet.  Then I open the popup for form ID 2, but don't save yet.  Then I go back to popup 1 and hit save. It submits the form from the 2nd popup.

I have tried several ways to make unique IDs, but it seems all the forms share variables, whether I do it in javascript or C# like 
    this <%: var myid = Guid.NewGuid(); %>
But it looks like myid gets overwritten as soon as I load another partial page popup.

Is what I am trying to do impossible? Or am I just stupid?

*** EDIT - I will try to make it clear:

I have a list of items, and each line of the list has a button.  When that button is pressed, it opens a popup of the partial page i have shown above.

```
ID  |  Button
-----------------
1   |  [ClickMe]    -opens popup->   [ _______  (SAVE) ]
-----------------
2   |  [ClickMe]    -opens popup->   [ _______  (SAVE) ]
-----------------
3   |  [ClickMe]    -opens popup->   [ _______  (SAVE) ]
```

So If I just open the popup for line 1, and enter some text and hit save, it will save the form on the popup (it is the only one)

But if I open popup 1, and then popup2 and then popup 3, they all start referencing the form in popup 3.  No matter what I do.

I have done what Lokesh suggested:
    form id= Model.Id.toString()

And That form will always be there, but when I click the SAVE button, it still takes the most recent popups form ID.  Is it the way I set up the javascript events?  I just need make sure if I click SAVE for popup 1, it will use the form defined in that same popup.

Comment: Read all of it but still not clear what you want to do. Can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: You said, you have database id for each item, right? you can use that. 
<form id="@Model.Id.toString()">